# click to skip slides in the slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have issues with skipping slideshow.

The slideshow has buttons that can be clicked to see next slides and the slideshow will get started from the clicked slide. If I don't click any, the slideshow will be auto played with buttons.

First issue is that if I click third button, it shows the third slide but the second slide is shown twice for the first two slides(skips the first slide) and goes to the third image and after that, it works fine. (automatic focusing for buttons along with slides are working fine)

Second issue is that once I click third button, even though I click other buttons, slides aren't changed and the slideshow is stuck with the last image(the third image).

This is my jquery function.

```
var images, buttons, iterator = 0, index, loop;

function stopLoop() {//stop setinterval once one of buttons is clicked.
clearInterval(loop);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.dotstyle button').bind("click", function(){
    stopLoop();
    slideshow($(this).index());
});
slideshow(iterator);
});

function slideshow(number){
images = $('#info-slide div'), //all slider images
buttons = $('.dotstyle button'),//all dot buttons

images.eq(number).fadeIn(800);
buttons.eq(number).focus();

loop = setInterval(function() {
    //save shown image ad focus button
    var now_button = buttons.eq(number);
    var now_image = images.eq(number);
    number += 1;//iterator for nex image
    //if is the last image go to first

    if (number == images.length) {
        number = 0;
    }

    $(now_image).fadeOut(2000);//hide shown image
    $(now_button).blur();//not focus button
    images.eq(number).fadeIn(2000);//show next image
    buttons.eq(number).focus();//focus next button
}, 6000);

}
```

This is my html

```
    <div id = "wallpaper">
        <div id = 'info-slide'>
            <div id = "1"><img src="photo1.jpg"/></div>
            <div id = "2"><img src="photo2.jpg"/></div>
            <div id = "3"><img src="photo3.jpg"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class ="dotstyle"><!-- Pagination -->
            <button id = "b1">1</button>
            <button id = "b2">2</button>
            <button id = "b3">3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my css

```
#info-slide > div{
position: absolute;
display: none;
height:100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

I am not sure if I explain the issues precisely but you would know if you play with my auto slideshow just few times. Please give me a solution

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hide all image then show selected index image, add `$('#info-slide>div').hide();` after `stopLoop();`

Comment: omg.. I though display: none was enough. that single line $('#info-slide>div').hide(); fixed everything. Thanks.. I was stupid :(

Comment: One more questions to ask you. I don't know why it happens. Every time a slide changes to the next one, screen position of the browser suddenly goes back (focus) to the slideshow when I scroll down to see in the browser. Do you know why it happens?

Comment: you're welcome.  it scroll because you have `buttons.eq(number).focus();`

Comment: oh. is there a way to prevent auto scroll or do I have to use other tag instead of <button> ?

Comment: try remove that `.focus()` because it not affecting the slides